# Repo Init fails while trying to download AOSP

Tags: android

I'm trying to download AOSP code.When i run below cmd:

**repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-12.0.0_r5**

I see below error

Downloading Repo source from https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo
repo: error: "git" failed with exit status 1
cwd: /mnt/sathya/.repo/repo
cmd: ['git', 'tag', '-v', 'v2.22']
stderr:

> > error: failed writing detached signature to '/tmp/.git_vtag_tmpWky6HE': No space left on device
> > fatal: double check your --repo-rev setting.
> > fatal: cloning the git-repo repository failed, will remove '.repo/repo'

What should be done to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It says you do not have enough space on the disk.

Comment: I have 250GB space on that directory.It worked when i ran after a restart.Not sure how it worked.Btw Thanks